# Python .words issue?

Tags: python, nltk, tokenize, sentiment-analysis, attributeerror

Ok so I'm trying to create a program that tells me how positive or negative each line of that paulryan.txt file is. I'm using the opinion_lexicon, and the file is '_io.TextIOWrapper'

Is there something I can use instead of .words?

Other less important problem: any ideas how to make my WHOLE paulryan.txt file lowercase while keeping it tokenized by line? Thinking it won't give me an accurate positive or negative score if I don't make the whole thing lowercase because there are only lowercase words in the opinion_lexicon.

```
import nltk  
from nltk.corpus import opinion_lexicon
from nltk.tokenize.simple import (LineTokenizer, line_tokenize)

poswords = set(opinion_lexicon.words("positive-words.txt")) 
negwords = set(opinion_lexicon.words("negative-words.txt")) 


f=open("paulryan.txt", "rU")
raw = f.read()
token= nltk.line_tokenize(raw)

print(token)

def finddemons():
    for x in token:
        y = token.words()
        percpos = len([w for w in token if w in poswords ]) / len(y)
        percneg = len([w for w in token if w in negwords ]) / len(y)
        print(x, "pos:", round(percpos, 3), "neg:", round(percneg, 3))

finddemons()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in finddemons
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'words'
```

Comment: I looks like you're confusing `spacy` interface with NLTK =) Try `from nltk import word_tokenize; y = word_tokenize(token)`

Comment: Hmmm. Well, I tried that but it merged everything into one big...thing :/ I need it to separate it by line, its a text document full of Tweets, one per line

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to read the file line by line. Then , use word_ tokenize:

```
for line in f:
    tokens = word_tokenize(line)
```

You are right about lowercase the text for searching in the lexicon :

```
for line in f:
    tokens = word_tokenize(line.lower())
```

You could even try to lemmatize the tokens by using wordnet, because the opinion lexicon is not that rich in vocabulary. Especially if you use tweets, where words are often in different forms.